# Adding a HTML tag to an ng-repeat block

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add a block of HTML to a `ng-repeat` block. the idea is to build up a breadcrumb trail, with a chevron between each item.

```
<div class="pull-left breadcrumbs">
    <span ng-repeat="crumb in breadcrumbs">
        {{crumb.display}} {{$last ? '' : '<span class=\'fa fa-chevron-right\'></span>'}}
    </span>
</div>
```

However, this does not render as expected.

I have also tried changing the single quotes for double quotes in the `class=` part of the HTML.

Comment: Just put the HTML right in there and use ng-if to control the rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with the [`ng-hide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) directive.
This directive hides an element, if the expression evaluates to true.

```
<div class="pull-left breadcrumbs">
    <span ng-repeat="crumb in breadcrumbs">
        {{crumb.display}} 
        <span class="fa fa-chevron-right" ng-hide="$last"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

or you could use the [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive.

```
<div class="pull-left breadcrumbs">
    <span ng-repeat="crumb in breadcrumbs">
        {{crumb.display}} 
        <span class="fa fa-chevron-right" ng-if="!$last"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to utilize the angularjs feature, track by $index.

```
$scope.maxlength = $scope.breadcrumbs.length-1;
```

And utilize the ng-show tag, to display the span only if it is not the last item in the repeater.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
   <span ng-repeat="crumb in breadcrumbs track by $index">
        {{crumb.name}} <span ng-show="$index < maxlength" class="fa fa-chevron-right">></span>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this indeed will work, but `$last` does this all for you more neatly.

Comment: That works, but it takes more code to do. Would be great in a more complex scenario.